# How to read/loop array in URL with coldfusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I am trying to read some url-parameters/array when using jQuery sortable:
https://linssen.me/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/

So far i did not figure out how i can loop trough the parameters in the url using coldfusion:

http://www.domain.com/update_sort.cfm?listItem[]=1&listItem[]=3&listItem[]=4&listItem[]=2

I would be very thankful for some help/hint.

Comment: `url` is a just a structure, so you can loop through it like `<cfloop collection="#url#" item="oneitem">`

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion(*) is not like PHP... adding `[]` to the URL parameter name on the query string doesn't make it an array on the server; what you *do* get is a comma-separated list of the values, which you can then convert to an array: `URL.listItem.listToArray()` (that's ColdFusion 11... you don't say which version of CF you're using: make sure to *always* specify that in your questions. You can then loop through that with `.each()` or `.map()` / `.reduce()` etc, depending on what you are wanting to do with your array.

If one is looking at *all* the parameters on the URL, then they're exposed as a structure, so you can loop through *those* with the struct equivalent of the `.each()` (etc) methods.

(*) ColdFusion isn't, but Railo and Lucee are I think. Or there's a setting to make them behave that way (you'll need to check that yourself).

Comment: Note that in order to make `URL.listItem.listToArray()` work, the parameter keys must not have the square brackets in them. Otherwise it needs to be `URL["listItem[]"].listToArray()`.

Comment: Good point. Sorry I took at is implied that I meant for the OP to lose the `[]` entirely for the purposes of their code.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion does not treat trailing square brackets in keys as an array. Instead something like

`listItem[]=1&listItem[]=3&listItem[]=4&listItem[]=2`

will be stored as:

`URL["listItem[]"] = "1,3,4,2"`

To achieve the desired behavior anyway, you can build your own URL scope. So instead of accessing the `URL` scope using `URL["listItem[]"]` and having to deal with a list (string), you can go `<cfset GET = transformQuery()>` and access the `GET` variable using `GET["listItem"]` to retrieve an array.

```
<cffunction name="transformQuery" access="public" output="false" returnType="struct">

    <cfargument name="queryString" type="string" default="#CGI.QUERY_STRING#" required="true">

    <cfset LOCAL.result = {}>
    <!--- OR to preserve key order (becomes case sensitive!)
        <cfset LOCAL.result = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init()>
    --->

    <cfset LOCAL.buffer = listToArray(ARGUMENTS.queryString, "&")>
    <cfloop array="#LOCAL.buffer#" index="LOCAL.kvp">

        <cfset LOCAL.key    = urlDecode(getToken(LOCAL.kvp, 1, "="))>
        <cfset LOCAL.value  = urlDecode(getToken(LOCAL.kvp, 2, "="))>

        <cfif reFind("\[[ ]*\]$", LOCAL.key)>

            <cfset LOCAL.key = reReplace(LOCAL.key, "\[[\s]*\]$", "")>

            <cfif structKeyExists(LOCAL.result, LOCAL.key)>

                <cfif isArray(LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key])>
                    <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key].add(LOCAL.value)>
                <cfelse>

                    <cfset LOCAL.tempBuffer = LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key]>

                    <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key] = []>
                    <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key].add(LOCAL.tempBuffer)>
                    <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key].add(LOCAL.value)>

                </cfif>

            <cfelse>

                <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key] = []>
                <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key].add(LOCAL.value)>

            </cfif>

        <cfelse>

            <cfif structKeyExists(LOCAL.result, LOCAL.key)>

                <cfif isArray(LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key])>
                    <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key].add(LOCAL.value)>
                <cfelse>

                    <!--- how to deal with keys that appear more than once, but do not contain the square bracket notation --->

                    <!--- overwrite value --->
                    <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key] = LOCAL.value>

                    <!--- OR append value (list)
                        <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key] = listAppend(LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key], LOCAL.value)>
                    --->

                    <!--- OR append value (array)
                        <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key] = [ LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key] ]>
                        <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key].add(LOCAL.value)>
                    --->

                </cfif>

            <cfelse>
                <cfset LOCAL.result[LOCAL.key] = LOCAL.value>
            </cfif>

        </cfif>

    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn LOCAL.result>
</cffunction>
```